# Android Dev Environment on Eclipse Indigo, Windows

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I am trying to set up subject environment on Eclipse 3.7.2 Indigo on Windows Xp. The Android SDK is installed successfully. When i install the Android Tools from the site

I recieve following error

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, 
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing:   
osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,18.0.0.v201203301601-306762
No repository found containing: 
org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,18.0.0.v201203301601-306762
No repository found containing: 
osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,18.0.0.v201203301601-306762
No repository found containing:    
org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,18.0.0.v201203301601-306762
No repository found containing:  
osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,18.0.0.v201203301601-306762
No repository found containing:        
org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,18.0.0.v201203301601-306762
No repository found containing: 
osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,18.0.0.v201203301601-306762
No repository found containing:   
org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,18.0.0.v201203301601-306762
No repository found containing:  
osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,18.0.0.v201203301601-306762
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/general/no-repository-found-containing-error-when-update-eclipse.html) to see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

What i did was to change the **https**://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ to **http**://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and it worked

Comment: @Landon: It should! Google recently changed their ADT download URL address to a standard HTTP. It was HTTPS previously!...

Answer (score 2):

I finally was able to get the things going by running SDK Manager from outside the eclipse like

```
Windows Start > Programs > android > android-sdk > right mouse click > run as  
administrator.
```

This helped, now I am able to install new packages. No such msg (failed to fetch blah blah)

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I had the same problem and found a solution using below methodology:

> “No repository found containing” Error when update Eclipse Posted on
>   April 21, 2009 by Devon A couple of days ago I started having issues
>   updating my Eclipse plugins. I’d get a “No repository found
>   containing” error for several of the repositories that it was trying
>   to update from. Here is a quick fix:
>
> Go to Help->Software Updates, then select the Available Software tab
>   and click the Manage Sites button
>
> Use the Export button to export the sites to a bookmarks.xml file Open
>   the bookmarks.xml file in your favorite text editor, and add a
>   trailing “/” to  any of the site urls which are missing the “/” on the
>   end. Save the changes. Back in the Manage Sites window within Eclipse,
>   select all of the sites and click the Remove button Now, click Import
>   and load in the edited bookmarks.xml file Now try your import again,
>   and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure you have installed the latest JDK and JRE files. Next once you've downloaded and installed Eclipse, go to Help->Check for updates, let this run through and ensure Eclipse is completely up to date. If it still doesn't work after this you may need to download the "GEF" install files, you can get the download address' from here: http://www.eclipse.org/gef/updates/index.php (simply "Add" these to your Eclipse "Available Software Sites" and download/install all the files).

Once this is all done you should be able to download and install Android for Eclipse without any issues (hopefully). This is what I had to do so hopefully it works for you too.

Comment: I did offline installation of ADT Plugin. Now when ever i start SDK Manager i get this error. Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml, reason: dl-ssl.google.com
Done loading packages. Its too annoying. whats the cause of this error please?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [bug thread from 2010](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6424) the problem was solved for me (in October 2013) by using a different URL:

Go to `Eclipse` / menu / `Window` / `Preferences` / `Install/Update` / `Available Software Sites`.

The enty for `Android Developer Tools Update Site` click `Edit`.

For `Location` give this url:

`https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/site.xml`

**Done!**

---

the previous url for me was `http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`. If you check them in a browser you can see which one works! For me, only the xml.

- xml https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/site.xml
- original http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6424